# Trying to remove 56 million '' / '' symbol from txt file

Tags: sed

I need to clean txt file from unwanted symbols.

`sed -i.old 's/Word//g' outfile.txt`
I have removed some words with this code but I can't remove / symbol.

`sed -i.old 's////g' outfile.txt sed: 1: "///d": invalid command code /` <- This is the error I get

`sed -i.old 's////g' outfile.txt` <- I have tried this code but I got an error

`sed: 1: "///d": invalid command code /`

Comment: Switch from `s///`to `s|||` or `s###` or `ssss`.

Comment: Or use leaning toothpicks `s/\///`

Comment: You *can* do `sed -e 's@/@@g`, but you should not. `tr` is much better for removing characters from a file.